# Why does Office.context.mailbox.item.dateTimeCreated return PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME not PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME?

Tags: outlook, office-js

`Office.context.mailbox.item.dateTimeCreated` for one particular message in my inbox returns what appears to be the PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME - **Tue Aug 20 2019 12:06:18 GMT+0100 (BST)** - rather than PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME (which is what is displayed on the message in the inbox). Why is that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the Outlook version and platform you are using? Please share the repro steps if possible.

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility - It was on Outlook for Web and for Mac. It's not possible to reproduce the steps unfortunately. I know the message was moved from different folders before this particular date appeared.